# Создать функцию, имеющую два аргумента и возвращающую в качестве аргумента число из отрезка [a,b] (С++)

Tags: c++, массивы, функции

Создать функцию, которая будет иметь два целочисленных параметра a и b, и в качестве своего значения возвращать случайное целое число из отрезка [a;b]. C помощью данной функции заполнить массив из 20 целых чисел и вывести его на экран. Помогите мне, пожалуйста. Надо чтобы эта функция генерировала разные числа.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>

#include <cstdlib>

#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int cluchaynoechislo(int a, int b) // функция принимает 2 целочисленных параметра и возвращает в качестве своего значения целое число из отрезка [a;b].

{
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
unsigned const int n = 20;
int A[n];
int cluchchislo;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
  cluchchislo = a + rand() % (b - a);
  A[i] = cluchchislo;
  }
return cluchchislo;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])

{

setlocale(0,""); // русификация

int a, b;

cout << "Введите первое число: ";

cin >> a;

cout << "Введите второе число: ";

cin >> b;

unsigned const int n = 20;
int A[n];

cout << "Элементы массива A: ";

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)

{

A[i] = cluchaynoechislo(a,b);

cout << A[i] << " ";

}

cout << endl;

system("pause");

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Что значит "генерировала разные числа"? Нужно гарантировать неповторяемость? Или речь о чем-то другом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вынесите инициализацию [гпсч](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB) в `main`:

```
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
```

не нужно вызывать инициализацию при каждом вызове функции.
Более того. Зачем вы каждый раз внутри функции заполняете массив случайных чисел. Если вам только одно надо? Можно переписать функцию так:

```
int random_int(int a, int b) {
    return a + rand() % (b - a + 1);
}
```

Comment: Там *отрезок* **[a, b]**, а не *интервал* **[a, b)**. А массив скорее всего из-за копипаста

Comment: @int3 Да, вы правы. Я взял формулу из имеющейся реализации.